# My project cannot connect to the Oracle 10G database

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle

When starting the project and pressing Contact gives an error
and I do not know how to solve the problem

My Code

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Types
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As New OracleConnection
        'conn.ConnectionString = "User Id=" + userID.Text &
        '  ";Password=" + password.Text &
        '  ";Data Source=" + dataSource.Text
        'conn.Open()
    End Sub
End Class
```

My Error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Test Oracel.exe

Additional information: The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection' threw an exception.
```

and When use

```
Imports System.Data.OracleClient 
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim CONNECTION_STRIN As String = "User Id=system;Password=admin;Data 
        Source=(DESCRIPTION=" +
       "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.80.30)(PORT=1521)))"
        Dim connection As New OracleConnection
        connection.ConnectionString = CONNECTION_STRIN
        connection.Open()
        End Sub
End Class
```

Get Error

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in System.Data.OracleClient.dll

Additional information: System.Data.OracleClient requires Oracle client software version 8.1.7 or greater.
```

Comment: Probably you can get more information about the problem looking at the InnerException field from your exception details

Comment: I did not understand what you mean

Comment: Have you tried OLE DB ?

Comment: Arent you missing the service or SID name in the connect string?

Comment: Also, what version of Oracle Client, or JDBC library are you using? Oracle 10g is ancient and unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types

Dim oradb As String = "Data Source= ip ;User Id= user  ;Password=      password     ;"
conn.ConnectionString = oradb
conn.Open()